# Bitmap scaling issue

Tags: android

I'm creating a Bitmap dynamically to be added to an HorizontalScrollView, specifying its size in density-independent pixels, as follows:

```
    int bmpWidth = dpToPixels(1300);
    int bmpHeight = dpToPixels(chart.getLayoutParams().height);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpWidth, bmpHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Where dpToPixels is a method merely converting pixels to dip:

```
private int dpToPixels(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

On an HD screen, i.e. having a width of 1080 pixels (tested on a Nexus 5 and an LG G2), the `dpToPixels` method determines that the BMP should have a size of 3900 pixels. However, the bitmap seems to have a width of about 1300 pixels on the screen. So I guess the Bitmap is actually rescaled by the system. How could I prevent this?

On the other hand, on a Galaxy S2, the conversion of 1300 dip gives 1950 pixels, and the resulting BMP seems to have that width, like it's not being rescaled. So I'm a bit confused...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A side note: chart.getLayoutParams().height will return height in pixels, not dp. So you will set the wrong height of Bitmap.

Comment: Gosh that was it, thanks! The height of my BMP was too big to fit its parent's, the reason why it was scaled down. Now it's displayed properly. Thanks again ;)